# Bash Process Substitution in exec line, some commands stopped working

Tags: bash, shell, exec, process-substitution

So I have a bash command using process substitution in an exec line that stopped working recently, and it boils down to this example:

Contents of script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash   
ls -l "$1" >/tmp/out  
echo "SUCCESS" > "$1"
```

This works, putting "SUCCESS" into `log`:

```
rm -f log; ./script.sh >(cat >log)
```

Using `tail` also works:

```
rm -f log; ./script.sh >(tail >log)
```

Using `exec` with `cat` works:

```
rm -f log; exec ./script.sh >(cat >log)
```

But.. `exec` with `tail` does **NOT** work:

```
rm -f log; exec ./script.sh >(tail >log)
```

In all cases, the contents of /tmp/out look okay, looking something like:

```
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 14 10:55 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[158518]
```

Why does `cat` work but not `tail` or `head`? This was working at sometime in the past.. is this a bash feature change or bug regression..?

```
bash --version: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 0):

So using `strace` on substituted process revealed that `tail` and `head` were getting a SIGHUP from the kernel before they had a chance to write. A simple workaround is to add `nohup` to the substitution:

> rm -f log; exec ./script.sh >(nohup tail >log)

I think I understand why this fails with exec. IIUC, >(tail >log) creates a child process of the current `bash` process. However when using exec, it now becomes a child process of `script.sh`. When script.sh exits, the kernel sends `SIGHUP` to all child processes.

Still not sure why this used to work, perhaps in newer kernel versions it is faster/more aggressive about sending its SIGHUPs.